# Is a link to a receiver is required for proper Command Design Pattern implementation?

Tags: design-patterns

Per GoF Design Patterns ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)), `ConcreteCommand` instance should (must?) have a link (reference) to a `Receiver` instance. I have following implementation of a command:

```
internal class PutBlockOntoBlockCommand : ICommand {
    private readonly int _srcTower;
    private readonly int _dstTower;

    public PutBlockOntoBlockCommand(int srcTower, int dstTower) {
        _srcTower = srcTower;
        _dstTower = dstTower;
    }

    public void Execute(Robot robot, Construction construction) {
        robot.MoveBlocks(_srcTower, _dstTower, construction);
    }
}
```

This co mmand instructs a robot to move blocks on the construction site. Notice that *instance* of the command has no reference to the *instance* of the receiver (a Robot); instead the command relies on the `Invoker` (a `RobotCommandCenter` in my case) to supply an instance of the `Robot` to execute the command.

I am convinced that for a command to be a command it shall *only* encapsulate the intention, and should *not* be responsible for specifying the target of the command. In my case, as a user, I do not care which robot will be used to execute the job.

**So my question is:** is it technically valid to refer to the presented implementation as a "Command Design Pattern"?

Answer (score 1):

First, there are no design pattern police.  It's always open to interpretation and colored in shades of gray.

Second, wikipedia is not as good as the original volume, make the investment in the book :)

The GoF list the intent of the Command pattern as:

> Encapsulate a request as an object, thereby letting you parameterize
>   clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support
>   undoable operations.

If you meet even one of these intents I'd say you can call it a Command derivative.

You can genrally tell something is a command if it holds the logic for implementing or invoking the desired effect, freeing the holder of the command reference from dealing with these details.  Often this is so encapsulated you can do cool things like put them in a list and use the common Execute method defined in the base to perform Redo and Undo very cleanly.

If your base class defined the Execute and your calling code passes all commands the Robot reference then you have a Command, but one with strategy or flyweight aspects that allow you to change the target of the commands.  I can see uses for this, though at the cost of things like undo/redo.

Comment: I have the book, couldn't link it, so I am referring to the source. There is no such thing as "English Police", doesn't mean "I is good" is correct. Notice that I asked if my implementation is "technically" a Command Design Pattern.

Comment: @THX-1138 That's what I meant though, I don't know that there is a "technical definition" to a Command pattern.  What I was trying to say with my humorous statement of "design pattern police" is that it is subjective.  My opinion is as I stated above though.